# Python: Formatting a list (which contains a list) for printing

Tags: python

I'm working on a project that translates input to Pig Latin (yeah, I'm sure you've never seen *this* one before...) and having trouble formatting my output.

(for the following, sentence = a list holding user input (phrase), split by phrase.split() )

```
sentence.remove(split)
final = map(str,sentence)
print "Final is (before formatting:", final
final = [sentence[0].capitalize()] , sentence[1:]
#finalFormat = ' '.join(final)
print "Final is", str(final).strip('[]')
#print "FinalFormat is", finalFormat
print "In Pig Latin, you said \"", ' '.join(map(str, final)), "\". Oink oink!"
```

What I get is:
"In Pig Latin, you said "['Firstword'] ['secondword', 'thirdword'] "

What I am looking for is:
"In Pig Latin, you said "Firstword secondword thirdword."

Based on my debug print statements it looks like my problem is still on the line (5 from the bottom):

```
    final = [sentence[0].capitalize()] , sentence[1:]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: The line `final = map(str,sentence)` is also irrelevant, since you overwrite that in the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
final = sentence[0].capitalize() , sentence[1:]
```

To this:

```
final = [sentence[0].capitalize()] + sentence[1:]
```

You were mapping a tuple of a string and a list, to strings, rather than a list.

Note: using `'single"'` quotes here will avoid `"this\""` ugliness.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding quickly! Unfortunately, either this didn't solve my problem, or it indicates that my problem is on another line. Output is now "In Pig Latin, you said " ['My'] ['ishfay', 'oodfay'] "" (for input "my fish food.")

Comment: Don't `map` the `final`, it's already strings so just `' '.join` it.

Comment: @user2113818: You've missed the `+` operator that wim suggested. Using a comma between two lists creates a tuple. Using + concatenates them.

Comment: Wim and Blckknght, thank you both so much! I really appreciate the assistance from both of you (and clearly need to check my eyeglass rx.)